# Why is this json decode printing to screen?

Tags: php, json

Something very odd is happening with this piece of php. Instead of filling the $country variable, it's printing the entire json onto the browser window. I don't understand why it's doing this.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://ipinfo.io/".$this_ip."/json");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36");
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Referer: http://www.example.com';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$json = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

 $decode = json_decode($json,true);
 $country = $decode[country];
```

Here's the entire error it spits out:

```
<body style="height:100%; overflow:auto; padding:0px; margin:0px;">{
  "ip": "8.8.8.8",
  "hostname": "google-public-dns-a.google.com",
  "city": "Mountain View",
  "region": "California",
  "country": "US",
  "loc": "37.3860,-122.0838",
  "org": "AS15169 Google Inc.",
  "postal": "94040"
}<br>
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>/var/www/html/example.php</b> on line <b>59</b><br>
```

Also, why am I getting this non-object error?

Comment: you need to replace with curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

Comment: If you want just the country you can also request http://ipinfo.io/$this_ip/country - see http://ipinfo.io/developers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);` to your curl

Comment: for your other issue, change `$country = $decode[country];` to `$country = $decode['country'];` you was missing the `'` on your array key

Answer (score 1):

Also

```
$country = $decode['country'];
```

instead of

```
$country = $decode[country];
```

Note how you are accessing the country key of the $decode array.